# MvcContrib Windsor Setup Component With Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, mvccontrib

I am using the MvcContrib library with Castle Windsor and I am having a problem
with setting a parameter when I register a component.

I have the following interfaces for classes that wrap a DataContext. I want 
to be able to specify which DataContext to use for different services because
I am connecting to several databases to retrieve data.

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    DataContext Context { get; }
}

public interface IReportingDC : IDataContext
{
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
```

public IDataContext DC { get; set; }

```
  public Repository(IDataContext dataContext)
  {
    DC = dataContext;
  }
}
```

Here are the registration lines from my global.asax.cs.

```
container.AddComponentLifeStyle<IDataContext, MainDataContext>(Castle.Core.LifestyleType.PerWebRequest);

container.AddComponentLifeStyle<IReportingDC, ReportingDC>(Castle.Core.LifestyleType.PerWebRequest);

container.Register(Component.For<IRepository<ReportingTotals>>()
.ImplementedBy<Repository<ReportingTotals>>()
.Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("dataContext").Eq("IReportingDC"))
.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
);
```

When I try and load the page I get the following error.

"Key invalid for parameter dataContext. Thus the kernel was unable to 
 override the service dependency"

Comment: please fix the code formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your component and use ServiceOverrides instead of Parameters:

```
Component.For<IReportingDC>()
         .ImplementedBy<ReportingDC>()
         .Named("IReporting")
         .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
```

and

```
Component.For<IRepository<ReportingTotals>>()
         .ImplementedBy<Repository<ReportingTotals>>()
         .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("dataContext").Eq("IReporting"))
```

See the [fluent API docs](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API) for reference.

Comment: Thanks I had just found that and got it working so I am glad you confirmed it for me.