# Strange LINQ Exception

Tags: .net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a similar issue to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191690/strange-linq-exception-index-out-of-bounds) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309235/asp-net-mvc-linq-exception):   I'm posting separately to provide additional information about the issue in my case, along with steps I've taken to debug it.

Basically the site works completely fine for 12+ hours and then suddenly stops working.  I'll start getting strange exceptions thrown in LINQ queries that have previously worked fine.

**I have included stack traces at the bottom of this post.**

Taking the advice found on similar SO posts, I deleted and remade my DBML by dragging the tables directly from the DB in Server Explorer.  Comparing the old and the new in Git, I found a few fields that differed:

- One instance of a varchar(255) being set as an nchar(10) in the dbml
- Two instances of varchar(255) that previously didn't have `NOT NULL` in the dbml
- An int(4) field previously didn't have `NOT NULL` in the dbml

*Some observations/notes*:

- The site works 100% fine for a while and then it just starts throwing these errors
- I can temporarily fix it by restarting the site in IIS **or** by restarting MSSQL server, but the problem usually comes back the next day
- I cannot figure out how to manually replicate it
- For some pages, I can reload them multiple times and get different but similar exceptions

  - I may get a `InvalidOperationException` on a line that calls `.Count()`, then reload it and get a `IndexOutOfRangeExcpetion` on a line that calls `.Any()` or `.First()`
  - Although the exception changes, I always get an exception on certain pages no matter what - they never disappear temporarily
- I'm using the repository pattern, so each of my classes have a repository class with a private DataContext member - could this be why?
- The site has a partial view with navigation items which comes from the db, and this always seems to load fine, but loading other things from the db fails.  Maybe this block is cached and that's why it continues to work?

The exception always seems to be thrown at this line:

`System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +4539`

**Any thoughts on why this happening and how to resolve the issue?**

**EDIT 1:**  I have added the relevant code above the corresponding stack traces. The exception gets throw when the last line of code executes.

Here are a couple stack traces I was able to copypaste before restarting the site:

```
IEnumerable<Chapter> toc = (from c in db.Chapters
    where c.Sections.Any()
    orderby c.ChapterNumber ascending
    select c);
return toc.Count();

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +4539
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +207
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +500
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +41
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +352
   MvcPaging.PagedList`1.Initialize(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 index, Int32 pageSize, Nullable`1 totalCount) in C:\path\to\my\project\MvcPaging\src\MvcPaging\PagedList.cs:63
   MvcPaging.PagedList`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index, Int32 pageSize, Nullable`1 totalCount) in C:\path\to\my\project\MvcPaging\src\MvcPaging\PagedList.cs:16
   MvcPaging.PagedList`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index, Int32 pageSize) in C:\path\to\my\project\MvcPaging\src\MvcPaging\PagedList.cs:10
   MvcPaging.PagingExtensions.ToPagedList(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize) in C:\path\to\my\project\MvcPaging\src\MvcPaging\PagingExtensions.cs:77
   MyNamespace.Controllers.ChaptersController.TableOfContents(Nullable`1 page) in C:\path\to\my\project\Controllers\ChaptersController.cs:73
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +118
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +784922
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +784976
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +37




var contentTop = (new PageRepository()).FindAllPages().Where(p => p.Slug == "login-top");
var contentBot = (new PageRepository()).FindAllPages().Where(p => p.Slug == "login-bottom");
ViewData["ContentAboveTheBox"] = (contentTop.Any() ? contentTop.First().HTML : String.Empty);



[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +4539
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +207
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +500
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +50
   System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1 source) +383
   MyNamespace.Controllers.AccountController.SetLoginContentAreas() in C:\path\to\my\project\Controllers\AccountController.cs:112
   MyNamespace.Controllers.AccountController.LogIn(String userName, String password, Nullable`1 rememberMe, String returnUrl, Nullable`1 IsEnc) in C:\path\to\my\project\Controllers\AccountController.cs:122
   MyNamespace.Controllers.AccountController.LoginPassThru() in C:\path\to\my\project\Controllers\AccountController.cs:82
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +784922
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +784976
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +453
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371
```

There was also an `InvalidCastException` thrown on one particular page.  Updating the dbml did not seem to fix this, but restarting the site did.

Comment: I have posted the LINQ queries above the corresponding stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you disposing your DataContext on each request (you should be)? Or do you have a single DataContext that lives forever (it sounds like this may be the case)?

It sounds like it could be a threading problem.

Comment: I am not currently disposing the DataContexts on each request.  I have one as a private member of a class that extends System.Web.Routing.RouteBase and another that extends MembershipProvider - perhaps one of these two is living forever?  All my repository models also have this as a private member, but these are always initialized in controller methods.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to implement `IDisposable` in my repository classes, keep the `DataContext` as a private member, and in the repo class's `Dispose()` method call `db.Dispose()`?  The controller logic would be updated to use `using(var pageRepo = new PageRepository()) { ... }`.  Just wondering if this is the right approach.

Comment: DataContexts should have a short lifespan. And they are not thread safe. If two threads try to access/alter the objects associated with the DataContext, it may become "corrupt"...forever. You should dispose the DataContext on each request...and instantiate a new one per-request. Some people choose to store it in the HttpContext.Current.Items and bind to the RequestEnd event to dispose of it.

Comment: Yes, it would be a very good idea, assuming you don't want to share a single DataContext across multiple repositories.

Comment: The alternative would be using(var dc = new MyDc()) { var repo1 = new Repo1(dc); var repo2 = new Repo2(dc); }

Comment: That makes sense to me and seems like the most likely cause.  Would you recommend storing it in `HttpContext.Current.Items`, or do you know of a better approach? (Bonus points for links to articles/tutes/sample code :P)

Comment: Well, I've seen it done both ways (storing it for the duration of the request vs. creating per LINQ query execution). If you're doing a lot of operations, storing it in the request has the benefit of not having the hit of recreating the DataContext each time. If you're using a dependency injection container, a very elegant solution can be to have your DataContext have a per request lifestyle registered in your container and have them automatically injected into your repository instances. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327664/mvccontrib-windsor-setup-component-with-parameter

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeff!  I think I'll implement a static method that does lazy initialization to place it into Current.Items and then bind to RequestEnd.  Dependency injection would definitely be the best option, but I don'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in your LINQ you're making a call to `.Single()` (or similar) which throws that exception if the `IQueryable` collection holds more than one element.

Next time, please post your code and not just your stack trace.

Comment: I don't see Single anywhere in the stack trace. And 
"Index was outside the bounds of the array" is coming from the QueryProvider itself.

Comment: Jeff is right.  I do have a couple calls to `.Single()` elsewhere, but these are wrapped in `try..catch` blocks and work fine.  The problem I'm having is that it always works until some point in time, and then it stops working.

Comment: The exception message: "Sequence contains more than one element" (found at the top of your stack) is specifically thrown by `.Single()` and `.SingleOrDefault()`, and that was the basis of my answer.